# How can I determine whether $(5x-1)^2$ is injective over the integers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

I believe I understand the one-to-one relationship, and can tell that this function is not injective over the reals. I'm having difficulty exploring the solution over just the integers. I believe that it is not injective, but how can I demonstrate this?

Answer (score 4):

Over the reals, $f(x)=f(y)$ and $x\neq y$ would mean that $5x-1=-(5y-1)$, which simplifies to $5(x+y)=2$. But if $x$ and $y$ are integers, this is a contradiction as the LHS is divisible by $5$ but not the RHS. So indeed $f$ is injective over $\mathbb Z$.